Adding Users to Azure AD B2C through an external application - NullException
I have been working on an admin app that lets users view, delete and add new users to an Azure AD B2C tenant. The issue is I keep getting a 'System.NullReferenceException' when it gets to .AddAsync(newUser);. I've ensured the app has read.write permissions in azure and that the tenantId, AppID and client secret are all correct, I've also updated all packages and .net
Below is a snippet for CreateUser, followed by an image of the exception the 'local variables?', I noticed createdUser has a value of null, but not sure what this means. Thanks in advance
public static async Task CreateUser(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Creating a new user...");

    // Collect user input for new user details
    Console.Write("Enter display name: ");
    string displayName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter given name: ");
    string givenName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter surname: ");
    string surname = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter email address: ");
    string emailAddress = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter password: ");
    string password = Console.ReadLine();


    var newUser = new UserModel
    {
        DisplayName = displayName,
        GivenName = givenName,
        Surname = surname,
        Password = password,
        Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>
{
    new ObjectIdentity
    {
        SignInType = "emailAddress",
        IssuerAssignedId = emailAddress
    }
}
    };

    try
    {

        var createdUser = await graphClient.Users
            .Request()
            .AddAsync(newUser);

        Console.WriteLine($"User '{createdUser.DisplayName}' with ID '{createdUser.Id}' successfully created.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine($"Error creating user: {ex.Message}");
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}

enter image description here
I've ensured the app has read.write permissions in azure and that the tenantId, AppID and client secret are all correct, I've also updated all packages and .nets
This is what the console shows when trying to onboard company (add user)
enter image description here

can you mention the nuget versions of Graph nuget and other nuget packages, so that it is easy to find the issue

instead of AddAsync() try with graphClient.Users.PostAsync(newUserModel); - ref link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

I tried the same with console application in local environment, the below code is working fine.
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;

namespace GraphApiConsole;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        // Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
        // single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
        var tenantId = "<tenantId>";

        // Value from app registration
        var clientId = "<clientId>";
        var clientSecret = "<clientSecret>";

        ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        var users = graphClient.Users.GetAsync().Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Users:{0}", users.Value.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Creating a new user...");

        // Collect user input for new user details
        Console.Write("Enter display name: ");
        string displayName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter given name: ");
        string givenName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter surname: ");
        string surname = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter email address: ");
        string emailAddress = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter password with Enough Complexity: ");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();

        var requestBody = new User
        {
            DisplayName = displayName,
            GivenName = givenName,
            Surname = surname,
            Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>
            {
                new ObjectIdentity
                {
                   SignInType = "emailAddress",
                   Issuer = "carbooking.onmicrosoft.com",
                   IssuerAssignedId = emailAddress,
                }
            },
            PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
            {
                Password = password,
                ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
            },
            PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration",
        };

        try
        {
            var result = graphClient.Users.PostAsync(requestBody).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("User created successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error creating user: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

I'm using the updated version of nuget package only
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.11.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.51.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

The code output is here

The user is created in adb2c

For More information.
You AD b2c Application must have User.ReadWrite.All and Directory.ReadWrite.All permissions need to be granted to do this operation.

The password should be strong
Issue should be your tenant id like ≤TENANTNAME≥.onmicrosoft.com



This was really helpful, issues solved now, thankyou! Appreciate the quick response a well!
